# Retrieve user's friends who like the same fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I try to find facebook api to retrieve user's friends who like the same fan page but I dont think the new graph api able to do this.

While searching in the stackoverflow, I came out with this FQL:

```
select user_id from like where object_id = "[page_id]" and user_id in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

but facebook return me with

```
array(0) {
}
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: Are you replacing the [page_id] place holder with the actual like object id?

Comment: ya replacing with my fan page id

Comment: have you already asked for user_likes permission and it has been granted?

Comment: I already get the permission for user_likes and friends_likes

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with FQL:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
    AND page_id = "[fan_page_id]"
```

Which returns you friends who are fans of given fan page ([fan_page_id]). It works at this moment quite well.

Comment: Can we get opposite of it , how to find that : how many page-likes are same between two friends , i am trying it by using :
my friend's id ( 100000000464783 ) 

SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = me() 
and 
page_id IN ( SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = 100000000464783 )